# windows phone 8 - cordova/phonegap device-plugin broken

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to use the **device plugin** in my cordova/phonegap application for windows phone 8.

I installed the **device plugin** using this command:

***plugman install --platform wp8 --project . --plugin https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git***

it seems to work as I dont get any error but just this message before ending:

*Installing "org.apache.cordova.device" for wp8*

this is my c**ordova_plugins.js**

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.device/www/device.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.device.device",
        "clobbers": [
            "device"
        ]
    },
   ...
];
module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{
    "org.apache.cordova.device": "0.2.12",
    ...
}
// BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

Fine, but when I try and use my plugin inside the onDeviceReady,

```
onDeviceReady : function() {

        console.log("device.platform: " + device.platform );
 ...
 }
```

it crashes with this error:
*The thread 0x77c has exited with code 259 (0x103).*

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to install a plugin was using CLI, which I highly recommend.